# SQL Server - sys.dm_exec_requests Issue

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-management-views

In SSMS 2008 I created a new query window and issued the following statement (notice I don't commit the transaction):

```
Begin Tran
Update Master.Part Set LastModifiedUser = 'me'
```

I then open another new query window and entered the following query:

```
Select * From sys.dm_exec_requests
```

The DMV does not show the query from the first query window. Anyone know why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement has technically completed, so it is no longer an active request, even though it is still holding locks and waiting for a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. You could instead query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

to find your SPID.